# Custom Callout View Button to Map

Tags: ios, swift, android-mapview

I am working on a MapView where on click of any custom annotation pin, I am showing custom callout view (load from xib file).

From this Custom Callout I have an UIButton, I already can detect click on this button but I want to access on the Map like the : view?.rightCalloutAccessoryView in the basic callout.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView,  {

    if view.annotation!.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self){
        return
    }

    let customView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! CustomCalloutView;
    let calloutViewFrame = customView.frame;
    customView.frame = CGRect(x: -calloutViewFrame.size.width/2.23, y: -calloutViewFrame.size.height+10, width: 315, height: 170)

    view.addSubview(customView)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: pinToZoomOn!.coordinate, span: span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

The route is correctly calculated from the classic callout but I can't know how to access my map from the button of my custom callout.

My CustomCalloutViewClass :

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class CustomCalloutView: MKAnnotationView {

@IBOutlet weak var goButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Button clicked sucessfully")
}

// MARK: - Detect taps on callout

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    if hitView != nil {
        superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self)
    }
    return hitView
}

override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let rect = self.bounds
    var isInside = rect.contains(point)
    if !isInside {
        for view in subviews {
            isInside = view.frame.contains(point)
            if isInside {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return isInside
}
}
```

If someone have an idea it will be helpfull I'm stuck on this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1: Capture a MKMapView instance in the closure passed to a CustomCalloutView

Add the closure which will be called on the button action. The closure will capture the `MKMapView` instance and you will be able to us is inside.

```
class CustomCalloutView: MKAnnotationView {
    var didTapGoButton: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        didTapGoButton?()
    }
}
```

#### Option 2: Add a weak reference to MKMapView as a property of the callout

This is not a clean solution but it may be an option under some circumstances. You only have to create a weak property storing a reference to `MKMapView` instance in `CustomCalloutView`

```
class CustomCalloutView: MKAnnotationView {
    weak var mapView: MKMapView?
}
```

#### Configuration

This is how you can wire up the `CustomCalloutView` for both solutions. Remember to use swift capture list to capture a weak reference to a `MKMapView` instance. Without it you may create a strong reference cycle.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)  {
    // ...
    let customView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! CustomCalloutView;
    // Option 1
    customView.didTapGoButton = { [weak mapView ] in 
        print(mapView?.annotations.count) 
    }
    // Option 2
    customView.mapView = mapView
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help !

I used the first option to capture the MKMapView instance.

If someone is stuck on the same issue you can use the first option and add this in your didSelect MapView function:

```
let selectedLoc = view.annotation
print("Annotation '\(String(describing: selectedLoc?.title!))' has been selected")

let location = view.annotation as! YourCustomClassType
let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
customView.didTapGoButton = { location.mapItem().openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions) }
```

Thank's

Comment: I'm glad that helped. However, I updated my answer a bit. In the first option please use swift capture list in the closure to avoid creating strong reference cycle between a map view and a callout. You should add `[weak mapView ]` in the closure definition. I forgot this pice at first, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

var didTapGoButton: (() -> Void)? this types of closures are very helpful for navigation from the view to viewControllers through the button actions  in the call layoutviews in the mkmapview.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use answers section for actual answering, not for comments, opinions etc. You can comment appropriate answer instead. If you think you provided another solution, please be more specific and explain how does it differ from the accepted one.